# Facebook User Profile Image expired?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm using DotNetOpenAuth to authenticate Facebook user and been able to get the return url of the user's profile image (in url).

Saved the url to database by the same url show up as in-accessible after 24 hrs. **Is the photo expired? or how to overcome this?**

Here's the sample url
[https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xap1/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/1560479_777973942267247_7573717326473478230_n.jpg?oh=963eb54ff09ef9a21fa0338db807f539&oe=552C077E&**gda**=1430702271_14d8653cc751102ea79d58b6ec11ccbb](https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xap1/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/1560479_777973942267247_7573717326473478230_n.jpg?oh=963eb54ff09ef9a21fa0338db807f539&oe=552C077E&__gda__=1430702271_14d8653cc751102ea79d58b6ec11ccbb)